# Can Cucumber hooks differentiate tags

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber, bdd

Ruby 2. I have an API realised as a module.  It defines a class as simply as

```
class Foo
  include API
end
```

but it's also used to extend another module *via*

```
module Bar
  class << self
    include API
  end
end
```

I want to test the behaviour both of an instance of Foo (*e.g.*, `Foo.new.`*methname*) but also the module functions (*e.g.*, `Bar.`*methname*).

One of my `Before` hooks defines `@exemplar` as the default object against tests should be applied.  So, the question: how can my `Before` hook tell whether it should use `@exemplar = Bar` or `@exemplar = Foo.new` ?

Alternatively, after playing with tags a bit, let me try a different approach.  If a scenario is tagged with `@a` and `@b`, and I have `Around('@a')` and `Around('@b')` hooks, and cucumber is invoked with `-t @a`, *both* hooks get invoked.  Is there a way the hook code can tell

1. What the `Around('...')` argument is (*i.e.*, the value of the `'...'`), and
2. What tags are actually in the set being applied?

*I.e.*, is there any way the `Around('@b')` hook can tell that it's for the `@b` tag expression, *and* that `@b` is **not** in the list of tags being applied?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your feature/scenario tagged ...

```
@some_tag
Feature: My feature

  @some_other_tag
  Scenario: My scenario
    Given ......
```

You can retrieve a list of your tag names when a given hook is applied by ...

```
Around('@some_tag') do |scenario|
  tags = scenario.source_tag_names
end
```

This would return a list of tag names in an array

```
$ tags
=> ['@some_tag', '@some_other_tag']
```

The tag that was called when the scenario was executed, lives in the Cucumber::Cli::Options object. I found a way to retrieve it, but it hurts my soul a little to post it ...

If you run the above with cucumber -t @some_tag, you can get the tag in your hook by doing the following ...(although, I'm sure there must be a better way)

```
Around('@some_tag') do |scenario|
  tags = scenario.source_tag_names
  options = Array.new puts
  executed_tag = options.last.config.tag_expressions
end

$ tags
=> ['@some_tag', '@some_other_tag']
$ executed_tag
=> ['@some_tag']
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see what you mean by soul pain! :-O
This is a great leap forward for me, although I'm still having trouble with multiple `Around()` stanzata.  I'm using `@test_instance` and `@test_module` values for the `-t` command-line option, but if a scenario is tagged with both, the selection of which `Around()` stanza is executed is weird. And I don't think the scenario block can be invoked multiple times in a hook. :-/